# How to find a p-value from t-stat

Tags: p-value

When you have a t-statistic and a standard error, how can you find a p-value?
Specifically, I am given this question a t-statistic of 1.363, and a standard error of 0.733.

And the following table:

[image]

The answer is a pvalue of  0.173. How do I find the pvalue?

Comment: The standard error doesn't seem to be relevant. Normal tables are only suitable for a t-statistic if you know the degrees of freedom are sufficiently large (which depends, among other things, on how far into the tail you need to look). Even if that was the case (that the unknown df were large enough), we don't have an alternative hypothesis to tell us which tail to look in (or indeed whether we need both tails). Of course if you know the answer it's possible to guess which it is (a two-tailed test) but presumably you were not supposed to use that information.

Comment: Which suggests you have left several relevant pieces of information out. Is this work for some subject, like an assignment, test, class exercise, or self-study?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

- What you're showing here is a table of Z-statistics (for the Normal distribution), not t-statistics (for the Student t distribution). If you really want to compute p-values for the $t$ distribution you'll need (1) to be told what the 'df' or degrees-of-freedom parameter is; (2) another set of tables that give values for the $t$ statistic.
- the standard error is irrelevant (maybe this is included by your instructor to see if you know you don't really need it?), the Z or t statistic already incorporates it ($Z = t = \mu/\sigma$).

- you can look up how to read a p-value from a $Z$ table [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-and-create-a-z-table-standard-normal-table-240e21f36e53), **except that the Z-table illustrated there is different from the one you're showing here**: your table shows the area under the curve between $Z=0$ and the value indicated by the row/column combination, whereas the table in the link shows the area under the curve between $-\infty$ and $Z$ (i.e., your values are 0.5 less than the values in the linked table, because $P(-\infty< Z <0)$ is 0.5)<sup>*</sup>.

  - the value in the "1.3" row and the "0.06" column is 0.413.
  - the upper tail probability (the probability that a draw from the standard Normal is $\geq Z$) is 0.5-0.413 (why subtract from 0.5? The probability that $Z>0$ is 0.5; the probability that $0<Z<1.36$ is 0.413; therefore the probability that $Z>1.36$ is 0.5-0.413)
  - the two-tailed p-value is $2 \times (0.5 - 0.413) = 0.174$ (as close as you can get to the specified answer with this table).

It's kind of weird that someone is asking you to do this; given the availability of statistics packages, it's a little bit like learning to light a fire without matches (without the fun and survival value).

In R, you would compute `2*pnorm(1.363, lower.tail = FALSE)`

---

<sup>*</sup> Please forgive abuse of notation ...

Comment: learning to light a fire without matches is actually useful

Comment: I agree 100%.  I'm much less sure that learning to find a p-value from a Z-table is useful.

Comment: Is there any possible reason for the 0.5?

Comment: edited ........

Comment: The $0.413$ is a rounded value for $1.36$, so for $1.363$ that may be a little more making the result double a little less than $0.174$.  Seeing $0.173$ is completely plausible